# Pandas compute rollling average after groupie

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am trying to compute the rolling means of values after grouping by.
My dataset looks like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03','2020-01-03'], 
               'weather': ['rain', 'sun', 'rain', 'sun', 'rain', 'sun', 'rain', 'sun', 'rain', 'sun', 'rain', 'sun'], 
               'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
```

[image]

Now, I want to have a rolling mean per day, and per weather.

While

```
>>>> df.groupby(['day', 'weather']).value.mean()
day         weather
2020-01-01  rain        2
            sun         3
2020-01-02  rain        6
            sun         7
2020-01-03  rain       10
            sun        11
```

proper computes the mean, the rolling version of it, does not seem to work?

```
>>>> df.groupby(['day', 'weather']).value.rolling(2).mean()
day         weather    
2020-01-01  rain     0      NaN
                     2      2.0
            sun      1      NaN
                     3      3.0
2020-01-02  rain     4      NaN
                     6      6.0
            sun      5      NaN
                     7      7.0
2020-01-03  rain     8      NaN
                     10    10.0
            sun      9      NaN
                     11    11.0
```

What's the right way of doing it?

I would expect an oputput that is the mean over multipel days i.e. (ingore the index)

```
day         weather    
2020-01-01  rain     2      2.0
            sun      3      3.0
2020-01-02  rain     6      4.0
            sun      5      5.0
2020-01-03  rain     8      8.0
            sun      9      9.0
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: I think you missunderstood `rolling`. It doesn't compress existing data to the mean value. It rather tries (for every row) to build the mean over the chosen window. If your groupby data has for example 10 rows, you get a result of 10 rows with rolling means.

Comment: Thanks for claryfying. How do i get a rolling mean over the groups? For example i would like to smooth the values of the means over 7 days per each group

Comment: I think I found a way. Don't know if it is the most efficient way but I'll update my answer

Comment: thank you! i think that's what i was looiking for. i would add the value to different column, but that's pretty much it

Comment: if you want a new column we don't need update. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the `NaN` values? Your window is set to `2` so the first value of each group will be set to `NaN` because of `min_periods`. Here is a quote of the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) :

> For a window that is specified by an integer, min_periods will default
> to the size of the window.

```
df.groupby(['day', 'weather']).value.rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean()

day         weather    
2020-01-01  rain     0      1.0
                     2      2.0
            sun      1      2.0
                     3      3.0
2020-01-02  rain     4      5.0
                     6      6.0
            sun      5      6.0
                     7      7.0
2020-01-03  rain     8      9.0
                     10    10.0
            sun      9     10.0
                     11    11.0
```

Was that what you are searching for?

**UPDATE**

You want a mean value for each day and wheather and than a rolling mean over x days of the computed mean (if I understand that right).
Try this:

```
out = df.groupby(['day','weather',],as_index=False)['value'].mean()
print(out)

          day weather  value
0  2020-01-01    rain    2.0
1  2020-01-01     sun    3.0
2  2020-01-02    rain    6.0
3  2020-01-02     sun    7.0
4  2020-01-03    rain   10.0
5  2020-01-03     sun   11.0
```

With the daily mean you can compute your rolling window:

```
out['rolling_mean'] = out.groupby('weather', as_index=False)['value'].rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean()['value']

print(out)

          day weather  value  rolling_mean
0  2020-01-01    rain    2.0           2.0
1  2020-01-01     sun    3.0           3.0
2  2020-01-02    rain    6.0           4.0
3  2020-01-02     sun    7.0           5.0
4  2020-01-03    rain   10.0           8.0
5  2020-01-03     sun   11.0           9.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is very close but I would expect that the value for 2020-01-02 and rain to be 4? as in the mean of 2 and 6?

Comment: the last line is erroring out for me? `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long'`

Comment: I got the same error when running it without `as_index = False`. Did you do that too?

Comment: @meto did my last update work for you ? problem solved ?

Comment: I just run the code as is, but I think there is a bug. `out.groupby('weather', as_index=False)['value'].rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean()['value']` does not have the same index as the original df so it doesn't add a colum cleanly